# Редактирование товаров к акции

Tags: mysql, sql

В общем есть раздел Акции и скидки, в которые добавляются акции.
К каждой акции можно прикрепить разные товары вместе с акционной ценой, хоть все несколько тысяч товаров.

Поле для выбора товаров и акционной цены товара клонируется на js, под каждый товар отдельные поля.

Под товары прикрепляемые к акции создал отдельную таблицу:

```
action_goods
------------
id
action_id (id акции)
good_id (id товара)
good_name (Имя товара)
action_price
```

Отношение один ко многим получается.
Так вот при создании/редактировании акции, я каждый раз грохаю все товары прикрепленные к акции и записываю заново те товары которые есть в форме.

Я понимаю что если будет добавлено к акции несколько тысяч товаров, не очень здорово их каждый раз перезаписывать.

Иначе не перезаписывать все заново, то может измениться цена акционная и каждый раз придется проверять прикреплен ли этот товар к акции или нет и соответственно выбирать для каждого товара  insert или update.

То последний вариант выглядит еще хуже.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то на странице у вас отображаются все товары из акции. И редактировать можно любой. Тогда решение:

1. К каждому товару на форме добавить поле `action` с возможными значениями

   - Nothing
   - Added
   - Updated
   - Deleted
2. По приходу формы на сервер, проверять это поле и выполнять соответствующее действие
3. Не запутаться с логикой модификации поля

   - Added + Updated = Added
   - Added + Deleted = Nothing
   - Updated + Deleted = Deleted

Comment: отличная идея! спасибо. и на сервере при формировании запроса к базе думаю группировать товары по действиям.

Comment: @md5hash Не обязательно. Можно сформировать три prepared запроса и для каждого товара выполнять нужный